# Send the output of a function as a message - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been writing something along the lines of a gambling bot as a learning project and have started with a basic game called 'Suicide' (simple game, bad name). As far as the game goes it works great however I would like to send the output of the function 'rolls' as a message into the channel the command was ran in.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def Suicide (self, ctx, StartNum, wager):
        ID = (ctx.author.id)

        con = sl.connect('balance.db')

        with con:
            CheckBalance = con.execute(f"SELECT Balance FROM USER WHERE DiscordID = {ID}").fetchone()
            CleanBalance = str(CheckBalance).replace("(", "").replace(")" , "").replace("," , "")
            if int(wager) > int(CleanBalance):
                await ctx.send('You dont have the balance to wager that much')
            else:
                con.execute(f"""UPDATE USER
                SET Balance = Balance - {wager}
                WHERE DiscordID = {ID}; """)

                await ctx.send(f"Starting game of suicide with a starting number of {StartNum}")
                # await asyncio.sleep(2)

                StartNum = int(StartNum)

                def rolls():
                    Roll1_result = int(randrange(1, StartNum))
                    print(f"Roll Result is {Roll1_result} / {StartNum}")
                    while Roll1_result != 1:
                        Roll2_result = int(randrange(1, Roll1_result))
                        print(f"Roll result is {Roll2_result} / {Roll1_result}")
                        Roll1_result = int(Roll2_result)
                    else:
                        print("Reached 1")

                rolls()
```

Does anybody know of a way to do this if possible. Please excuse the messy code and variable names.

In case it is needed here is an example of the output i would like to send either in the form of an embed or a multi-line message

```
Roll result is 33 / 53
Roll result is 15 / 33
Roll result is 10 / 15
Roll result is 4 / 10
Roll result is 2 / 4
Roll result is 1 / 2
Reached 1
```

Comment: Okay, so you see where the code says `await ctx.send(f"Starting game of suicide with a starting number of {StartNum}")`, and it causes the result of `f"Starting game of suicide with a starting number of {StartNum}"` to be sent as a message? That's what happens, because that's the thing that is being passed to `await ctx.send`, right? You want to send the result of `rolls()` as a message, right? So - did you try using the same technique? What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Ah, I see. It seems you wanted the messages passed to `print` to be sent as messages instead. Well you see, those things that you pass to print *are not the "output"* of the `rolls` function. That said, you certainly can make `rolls` be an async function as well, and then have it directly `await ctx.send` its own messages.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the response, managed to fix it using the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `print()` with `ctx.send()` or

```
pastRolls = []
def rolls():
                    Roll1_result = int(randrange(1, StartNum))
                    pastRolls.append(f"Roll Result is {Roll1_result} / {StartNum}")
                    while Roll1_result != 1:
                        Roll2_result = int(randrange(1, Roll1_result))
                        pastRolls.append(f"Roll result is {Roll2_result} / {Roll1_result}")
                        Roll1_result = int(Roll2_result)
                    else:
                        pastRolls.append("Reached 1")
rolls()
for thing in pastRolls:
    ctx.send(thing)
```

Comment: Thanks so much dude, used the for loop as it wasn't an async function. works a charm